# Can we set Url for g:Image in Css rather than in View.java in Gwt UiBinder?

Tags: css, image, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

```
<g:Image ui:field="myImage" url="/images/icon/close.png" />
```

This code work fine, but the following will not work

```
.myCss { background: url(/images/icon/close.png);}
```

I asked this question cos of this issue. Let image u need to use close icon in 10 Presenters. When user mouses over this icon it will call closeHover.png. So if we set url in TestView.java, then we have to do that for another 10 Views. But if we set Url at Css, we don't need to code 10 times?

Can we set Url for g:Image in Css rather than in View.java in Gwt UiBinder?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes you can. Just give it a regular CSS class, and not a `ui:style` name so it won't get obfuscated.

But why are you using a `<g:Image>` for this? Why not a Button or a div (HTML or Label)?

Comment: it is an icon png file.

Comment: I don't think that code in your question will work because you are trying to set the background on hover, which will be covered by the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ui:image` with `@url`.

First, move the image to the same package of your uiBinder class instead of using the `war/images/icon` folder.

Then use the following code:

```
<ui:image field="myIcon" src="close.png" />

<ui:style>
@url myIconRef myIcon;
.myCss { background: myIconRef;}
</ui:style>
```

If you want to put the image in another package, no problem. You can reference it using relative path like:

```
<ui:image field="myIcon" src="../images/icon/close.png" />
```